# Xamarin Hot Restart - App crashes if Static Property from generated class (using Text Template) is used

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-community-toolkit

I am using Hot restart to debug directly to my IPhone. The App only crashes while using Hot Restart in the Emulator using Cloud Solution the app works just fine.

I Have a .Resx File AppResources and I am using Translate extension provided from Xamarin Community Toolkit, to be able to use the keys from my .Resx I used Text Template that generates the keys with their names to be able to call them like this:

```
<Label Text="{toolkit:Translate Text={Static t4:AppResources.Key}}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
<Label Text="{Static t4:AppResources.Key}" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
```

The app crashes one I try to use

> Static t4:AppResources.Key

I have no Idea what I am doing wrong. I uploaded the Solution GitHub : [GitHub Link](https://github.com/obenyaala/TF4XamarinIPhone)

Is there a fix for the problem, or another way to be able to get the keys from .Resx File.

Thank you for your Help

This is the crash report.

> ## =======================================
> Native Crash Reporting
> =======================================
> Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates a fatal
> error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries  used by your
> application.
>
> =========================================
> Native stacktrace:
> =================================================================
>
> 0x102370120 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
>
> 0x102366cbc -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash     0x102373a60 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug    0x1d06bc29c -
> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib :      0x102514ec4 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
>
> 0x102514ec4 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full  0x102514ec4 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full  0x10250feb0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke    0x102376d3c -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke  0x1024252c0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked  0x102428728 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke  0x102508ccc - /pr
> ivate/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline   0x10250e0cc -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline  0x10250ec70 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arm64_common_trampoline  0x1874cf7a8 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x1874d123c -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x1874d7388 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186b2ac98 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x187093f58 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
> _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask     0x186b2b830 - /System/Library/Pr ivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186b2b2f0 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186b2b640 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186b2ae7c -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186b333c0 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186fa1970 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x1870acd68 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
> _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext     0x186b330b8 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x18695afa0 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186959920 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x18695abc8 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>    0x1874d5528 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x186fcafd0 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x1940775d8 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1940a2d44 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1940866a4 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1940a2a0c -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1846d281c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>     0x1846d630c - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib :
>     0x1940cafa0 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1940cac30 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices
> :   0x1940cb184 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/F
> rontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : 
> 0x184a5f9e8 -
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>     0x184a5f8e4 -
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>     0x184a5ebe8 -
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>     0x184a58bc8 -
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
>     0x184a58360 -
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation :
> CFRunLoopRunSpecific  0x19c096734 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
> : GSEventRunModal     0x1874d3584 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
>     0x1874d8df4 -
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore :
> UIApplicationMain     0x10251c8fc -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall     0x10251b010 - /private/
> var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper  0x102511a8c -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full  0x10250feb0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke    0x102376d3c -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke  0x1024252c0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked  0x10242b974 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_try_invoke_array    0x1023d39c4 -
> /private/var/containers/
> Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke     0x1023e3b68 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw     0x10251c8fc -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall     0x10251b010 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper     0x102511a8c -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full  0x10250feb0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke    0x102376d3c -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-4
> 3D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS :
> mono_jit_runtime_invoke   0x1024252c0 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked  0x10242a564 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked   0x10235b8f4 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec    0x10250d984 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main     0x102323c34 -
> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/95CE4E70-9227-43D7-A04D-AD08B0B10CC9/TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main     0x184714cf8 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib :
>
> ===========================================================
> ======    Basic Fault Address Reporting
> ================================================================= Memory around native instruction pointer (0x102517878):0x102517868  20
> 01 1f d6 18 0b 00 91 48 83 5f f8 08 10 00 b4   .......H.*.....
> 0x102517878  08 11 40 b9 48 83 1f b8 08 03 40 79 a9 0f 00 b0
> ..@.H.....@y.... 0x102517888  29 a1 33 91 28 79 68 f8 00 01 1f d6 48
> 83 5f f8  ).3.(yh.....H.*. 0x102517898  e8 0e 00 b4 08 01 40 f9 08 01
> 40 f9 08 69 40 39  ......@...@..i@9
>
> ## =========================================     Managed Stacktrace:
> ========================================    at  <0xffffffff>       at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain
> <0x000b8>       at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00020>       at
> UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00038>      at
> TF4FileIphoneTest.iOS.Application:Main <0x00012>    at
> :runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>      at 
> <0xffffffff>    at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:InternalInvoke
> <0x00030>       at System.Refle ction.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke <0x000fc>
> at System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke <0x0001a>    at
> Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x00254>    at
> :runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
>
> The app has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the way keys were generated.

Changed it from

```
    internal static string <#= entry.Name #>
{
    get { return nameof(<#= entry.Name #>); }
}
```

To

```
internal static string <#= entry.Name #> = "<#= entry.Name #>";
```

The app stopped crashing

Answer (score 0):

Static iOS libraries and frameworks are not supported and you may see runtime errors or crashes if your app attempts to load these. Use the HOTRESTART preprocessor symbol to prevent this code from executing. Dynamic iOS libraries are supported. For details, please refer to ([https:/ /learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart))

Comment: Does loading a static method count as static library or framework ?